# How to remove restrictions of Powerpoint 2016 Presentation

Tags: powerpoint, powerpoint-2016

I am only allowed to view the PowerPoint presentation, not to print it, or to copy from. Since it is a tutorial I would appreciate if someone could help me to copy code out of it instead of screenshooting it and feed it to a AI to get the text.

**What I allready tried:**

I renamed it to .zip and opend it with 7zip. But the 2016 version does not make it as simply to remove some text in a XML as descriped otherwhere.

Comment: Presumably the author password protected it for a reason. It would be up to them to give you an unprotected version or to provide the portions of the presentation you're asking for.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg say the password is lost since the user created it is no longer available. I just want to copy what I see instead of giving it to someone to type it

Comment: If the password isn't available, your best bet may be to make screen captures then use text recognition software to convert the images into text.  OneNote can do this, for example.

Comment: Im gonna Brute-force the password..